# are there any good web third party tools to do excel like pivot tables

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pivot-table

i am using asp.net mvc so the solution can be either server side or client side (jquery, etc).

i can't seem to find any good tools that can mimic excel pivot tables (allow user to get the pivot table experience that they get with excel pivot tables) on the web with good performance.

Comment: This would be a fantastically useful tool, especially if the pivot points could be created by dragging the column headers.

Comment: What is the data source? OLAP cubes, SQL db or other?

Comment: [Web Pivot Table](http://webpivottable.com) is exactly this kind of tool. Here is [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) and [documents](http://webpivottable.com/documents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/products/analysis/) or [jasper analysis](http://www.jaspersoft.com/jasperanalysis).

If you are willing to pay for a commercial BI solution, I would recommend Crystal Reports and Business Objects.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Jasper is Java based. The OP is using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Jasper is a good solution -- it can be used with simple Java wrapper code, even if you are not going to write the app in Java.

Answer (score 3):

You can try ASPxPivotGrid from [Devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/). Here is an [example](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxPivotGridDemos/SampleReports/CustomerReports.aspx). It has nice look & feel and drag & drop support.

Comment: can you use this in asp.net mvc or is this a server control ?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [OAT Pivot Table](http://oat.openlinksw.com/index.html?pivot).

Answer (score 1):

m-Power has a web pivot table template.  Here's a live demo of a [Web pivot table](http://www.crazybikes.com/mrcjava/servlet/CBB2E.R00180s) built with m-Power.  It operates very much like an Excel pivot table would, only it's all web based.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [pivot table component](http://www.flexmonster.com/flash-pivot-table-component) by Flexmonster.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dundas.com/Components/Products/Chart/NET/OLAP/index.aspx

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Pivot_Grid

http://www.radar-soft.com

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164070.aspx